# Is there an offline formatter software to minify/beautify code?

Tags: windows, offline, source-code, code-beautification

How do you routinely minfy or beautify your code?

***Dreamweaver*** doesn't do it.

***Eclipse*** doesn't do it (not even via plugin).

***phpDesigner*** does it, but I hate its interface.

***Notepad++*** could do it via plugin, but I could only find a js and a SQL formatter.

I know there are great online tools to do this, but I'd rather have something installed offline I can always/quickly use.

I work with PC and I am mostly interested in compressing and decompressing CSS and Javascript code.

Comment: You might want to look at command-line tools, like uglifyjs and cleancss.

Comment: It's a good idea but they're both packages for node.js, I'm not into it that much. I'm a GUI person...

Comment: Anyway, the answer seems to be Sublime Text, which has packages for both minifying and beautifying, plus a ton of other stuff worth exploring.